# Validaciones con DataAnnotations para dar un alta y para una edicion con un mismo modelo

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Mi problema es el siguiente.

Tengo un modelo de persona en el cual valido todos los atributos, incluso si su numero de documento ya existe para dar un Alta o no permitir hacerlo hasta que cambie su documento.
Al hacer una edición quiero evitar crear un segundo modelo (que repetiría prácticamente lo mismo) sacando la validación del documento.

Me encuentro con el problema que para la edición, al traer la información de la base de datos me dice que ese DNI ya se encuentra registrado y no me permite avanzar.

Si existe alguna forma de que en la edición pueda obviar la verificación del DNI sin necesidad de repetir el modelo inicial me ayudarían mucho.

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

y el código?, de como estas obteniendo la información?; lo que yo hago es crear una vista parcial con los datos en común y unicamente los incluyo en donde deben ser, por ejemplo te pongo mi modelo en común

```
 @model WebDBT.Models.MtoInvesMercado
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/AdminElegant/assets/node_modules/html5-editor/bootstrap-wysihtml5.css" />
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-5">
    <h4 class="card-title">Coordinación de Control de Abasto</h4>
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">                    
                <label>Ejercicio</label>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Ejercicio, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Ejercicio, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">                    
                <label>Oficio Solicita la I.M</label>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OficioCAASolIm, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OficioCAASolIm, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--/span-->
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">Fecha del Oficio</label>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FechaCCA, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control datepicker-popup", @type = "text" } })                    
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FechaCCA, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--/span-->
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Comentarios CCA</label>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ComentariosCCA, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ComentariosCCA, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-7">
    <h4 class="card-title text-success">División de Bienes Terapéuticos</h4>
    <hr>
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">                    
                <label>Oficio se Solicita I.M</label>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OficioDBTSolIm, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OficioDBTSolIm, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--/span-->
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">Fecha del Oficio</label>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FechaDBT, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control  datepicker-popup", @type = "text" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FechaDBT, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--/span-->
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">                    
                <label>Oficio D.B.T. Notifica a C.A </label>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OficioDBTEnvia, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OficioDBTEnvia, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--/span-->
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">Fecha del Oficio</label>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FechaDBTEnvia, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control datepicker-popup", @type = "text" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FechaDBTEnvia, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--/span-->
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Comentarios DBT</label>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ComentariosDBT, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ComentariosDBT, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

y luego en el create

```
    @model WebDBT.Models.MtoInvesMercado
    @{ ViewBag.Title = "Create"; }
     <link href="~/Content/AdminElegant/assets/node_modules/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header bg-info">          
           <h4 class="m-b-0 text-white">Registro de Investigación de Mercado</h4>
                 </div>
                 <div class="card-body">
                    @using (Html.BeginForm())
                    {
                        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        <div class="form-body">
                            @Html.Partial("_Mercado")
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-actions text-right">
                            <button id="BtnSubmit" type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success"> <i class="far fa-save"></i> Guardar</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Index", "MtoInvesMercados")'"><i class="fas fa-times-circle"></i> Cancel</button>
                        </div>}               
                </div>
            </div>
    
        </div>
    
    </div>
    
    
    @section Scripts {
        @Scripts.Render(
            "~/bundles/jqueryval",
            "~/Content/AdminElegant/assets/node_modules/moment/moment.js",
            "~/Content/AdminElegant/assets/node_modules/html5-editor/wysihtml5-0.3.0.js",
            "~/Content/AdminElegant/assets/node_modules/html5-editor/bootstrap-wysihtml5.js",
            "~/Scripts/WebScript/MtoInvesMercados.js" 
            )
    }
```